# Como puedo ordenar una tabla en react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una tabla en [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) la cual está de la siguiente manera:

```
<table className="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr className="titlesRow">
      <th>
        <p>{this.props.value == 1 && "Id company"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 2 && "Id contacto"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 3 && "Id Freelace"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 4 && "Id colaborador"}</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>{this.props.value == 1 && "Razon social"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 2 && "Nombre"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 3 && "Razon social"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 4 && "Nombre"}</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>{this.props.value == 1 && "Nombre comercial"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 2 && "Apellido"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 3 && "Nombre comercial"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 4 && "Apellido"}</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>{this.props.value == 1 && "Sitio Web"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 2 && "Email alterno"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 3 && "Sitio Web"}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value == 4 && "Numero de colaborador"}</p>
      </th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
      this.state.table.map((item, index) => {
        return(
          <div key={index}>
            {
               this.state.value == 1 &&
                 <tr key={index}>
                   <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                   <td>{item.razon_social}</td>
                   <td>{item.nombre_comercial}</td>
                   <td>{item.sitio_web}</td>
                   <td>{item.email}</td>
                   <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
            {
               this.state.value == 2 &&
                 <tr>
                   <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                   <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                   <td>{item.apellido}</td>
                   <td>{item.email_alterno}</td>
                   <td>{item.email}</td>
                   <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
            {
               this.state.value == 3 &&
                 <tr>
                   <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                   <td>{item.razon_social}</td>
                   <td>{item.nombre_comercial}</td>
                   <td>{item.sitio_web}</td>
                   <td>{item.email}</td>
                   <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
            {
               this.state.value == 4 &&
                 <tr>
                   <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                   <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                   <td>{item.apellido}</td>
                   <td>{item.numero_colaborador}</td>
                   <td>{item.email}</td>
                   <td><a className="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                 </tr>
            }
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
  </tbody>
```

Sé que la parte de `<tbody>` no está ordenada de manera correcta ya que todo esta dentro del `div`, deseo que al realizar la validación de que cuando el estado "table" cambie, me muestre diferentes campos.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?**

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedo solucionado.
solo cambie la parte del `<tbody>` de la siguiente manera

```
<tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.table.map((item, index) => {
                            return(
                                <tr key={index}>
                                {
                                     this.props.value == 1 ?
                                        <React.Fragment>
                                            <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                                            <td>{item.razon_social}</td>
                                            <td>{item.nombre_comercial}</td>
                                            <td>{item.sitio_web}</td>
                                            <td>{item.email}</td>
                                            <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>        
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                        : null
                                }
                                {
                                    this.props.value == 2 ?
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                                        <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                                        <td>{item.apellido}</td>
                                        <td>{item.email_alterno}</td>
                                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                                        <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                        : null
                                }
                                {
                                    this.props.value == 3 ?
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                                        <td>{item.razon_social}</td>
                                        <td>{item.nombre_comercial}</td>
                                        <td>{item.sitio_web}</td>
                                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                                        <td><a className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                        : null
                                }
                                {
                                    this.props.value == 4 ?
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <td>{item.iddef_cliente}</td>
                                        <td>{item.nombre}</td>
                                        <td>{item.apellido}</td>
                                        <td>{item.numero_colaborador}</td>
                                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                                        <td><a className="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a></td>
                                        </React.Fragment>
                                        : null
                                }
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            }
                        )
                    }
                 </tbody>
```

Saludos